# Levi-Civita symbol identity: $\epsilon_{ijs}x_s L_i = -\epsilon_{ijs}x_i L_s$

Tags: tensors

I have the following identity I want to use but don't know whether it's correct or not (and if it is, why so):

$$\epsilon_{ijs}x_s L_i = -\epsilon_{ijs}x_i L_s$$

Is this correct? How to arrive at this result using standard properties of the Levi-Civita symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $\epsilon_{ijs} = -\epsilon_{sji}$, so switch $s$ with $i$ and you're done:

$$\epsilon_{ijs}x_s L_i = \epsilon_{sji}x_i L_s = -\epsilon_{ijs}x_i L_s.$$

The first equality is just a change of index labels throughout.  The second equality uses the properties of the Levi-Civita symbol.

Comment: But I thought you are only allowed to switch the indices of the actual symbol itself, not of the stuff that stands after it? Sorry if this is trivial but I've just begun learning this notation and it's confusing to me.

Comment: Or is it the other way around - when changing indices on the LC symbol, you must change them appropriately on the stuff it 'operates' on?

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot, John!

Comment: It was my pleasure.